# The values in the model dont pass to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am uploading file using jquery and passing three parameters to controller. I can pass 1 of the parameter and other 2 parameters are selected from dropbox. 2 parameters from the drop box does not seem to bind in below code at uploader

```
params: {fileType: @Model.fileType, employeeId: @Model.employeeId,  trainId: @Model.trainId },
```

below is my code for uploading file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        // This function does nothing.  It won't spawn a confirmation dialog   
        // But it will ensure that the page is not cached by the browser.
    }; 

    var button = $('#fileUpload')[0];
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: button,
        allowedExtensions: ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf'],
        sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
        action: '/Home/UploadFileToServer',
        multiple: false,
        params: {fileType: @Model.fileType, employeeId: @Model.employeeId,  trainId: @Model.trainId },
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/DetailsFiles",
                data: { id: @Model.employeeId },
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#employee_files").html(data);
                }
            });
        }});
```

My view model is as follows:

```
 public int employeeId;
public int fileType;
public int trainId;
public File file;
public SelectList FileTypeList { get; set; }
public SelectList TrainingList { get; set; }
```

My dropboxes are :

```
<div id="trainFile">
        <div class="editor-label">
            Dosya Tipi
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.fileType, Model.FileTypeList)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Eğitim
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.trainId, Model.TrainingList)
        </div>
    </div>
```

To upload file using the following div:

```
<div id="fileUpload">
    <noscript>
        <p>
            Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
        <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
    </noscript>
</div>
```

I can not understand why the values are not bind to the model properties. I hit debug point on controller and see that only 1 parameter value is passed .What is the reason and how can i fix this?

**EDIT1**

It seems that the values selected from dropdown list is not binded to variable.

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing other params in data, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // This function does nothing.  It won't spawn a confirmation dialog   
    // But it will ensure that the page is not cached by the browser.
}; 

var button = $('#fileUpload')[0];
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: button,
    allowedExtensions: ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf'],
    sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
    action: '/Home/UploadFileToServer',
    multiple: false,
    params: {fileType: @Model.fileType, employeeId: @Model.employeeId,  trainId: @Model.trainId },
    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/DetailsFiles",
            data: { id: @Model.employeeId, fileType: @Model.fileType, traindID: @Model.trainId  },
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#employee_files").html(data);
            }
        });
    }});
```